# Spring boot interacts with Postgresql on different machine

Tags: spring, spring-boot, postgresql-9.3

I am new to Spring boot .I want to integrate my flow to read or insert data in postgressql ,I used crud repository but the save operation does not save anything on my postgresql hosted on a different machine.FindAll and find command also give data added by save operation but not what i added myself on Data base

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://160.110.67.94:5432/postgres 
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Controller

```
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
 import com.experian.model.RiskScoreBusinessRules;
 import com.experian.repo.RiskScoreBusinessRulesRepository;

 @RestController





  public class WebController {
    @Autowired
RiskScoreBusinessRulesRepository repository;
   @RequestMapping("/save")   
  public String process(){

    repository.save(new  RiskScoreBusinessRules("Inherent Risks","Client`s     business based risks", "Demographic","Client Location","Border crossings (airports, ports, marinas, Land border-crossings",120,"<89","89 to 178", ">178", "BR "));    

    //repository.save(new  RiskScoreBusinessRules("Adam", "Johnson"));
   // repository.save(new  RiskScoreBusinessRules("Kim", "Smith"));
   // repository.save(new  RiskScoreBusinessRules("David", "Williams"));
   // repository.save(new  RiskScoreBusinessRules("Peter", "Davis"));
    return "Done";
}
 //  public  static final String customer_uri = "riskScore";
@RequestMapping("/findall")
public String findAll(){
    String result = "<html>";


    for(RiskScoreBusinessRules riskBR : repository.findAll()){
        result += "<div>" + riskBR.toString() + "</div>";
    }

    return result + "</html>";
}


@RequestMapping("/findbyGroupName")
public String fetchDataByGroupName(@RequestParam("groupName") String groupName){
    String result = "<html>";

    for(RiskScoreBusinessRules riskBR: repository.findByGroupName(groupName)){
        result += "<div>" + riskBR.toString() + "</div>"; 
    }

    return result + "</html>";
}
```

}

model

```
 import java.io.Serializable;

 import javax.persistence.Column;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
 import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
 import javax.persistence.Id;
 import javax.persistence.Table;
 @Entity

 @Table(name = "RiskScoreBusinessRules")

 public class RiskScoreBusinessRules implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
@Column(name = "groupName")
private String groupName;
@Column(name = "categorization")
private String categorization ;
@Column(name = "subCategorization")
private String    subCategorization;
@Column(name = "riskAttribute")
private String  riskAttribute;
@Column(name = "parameters")
private String   parameters;
@Column(name = "weighting")
private  float  weighting ;
@Column(name = "normalisedScore")
private float   normalisedScore;
@Column(name = "maximumScore")
private float   maximumScore;
@Column(name = "actualScore")
private int   actualScore;
@Column(name = "lowValue")
private String  lowValue ;
@Column(name = "mediumValue")
private String  mediumValue ;
@Column(name = "maxValue")
private String   maxValue ;
@Column(name = "lastUpdatedBy")
private String  lastUpdatedBy;
    public RiskScoreBusinessRules(String groupName, String categorization, String subCategorization,
        String riskAttribute, String parameters, int actualScore, String lowValue, String mediumValue, String maxValue, String lastUpdatedBy)

        //float weighting, float normalisedScore, float maximumScore,
         {
    super();

    this.groupName = groupName;
    this.categorization = categorization;
    this.subCategorization = subCategorization;
    this.riskAttribute = riskAttribute;
    this.parameters = parameters;
    //this.weighting = weighting;
    //this.normalisedScore = normalisedScore;
//  this.maximumScore = maximumScore;
    this.actualScore = actualScore;
    this.lowValue = lowValue;
    this.mediumValue = mediumValue;
    this.maxValue = maxValue;
    this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RiskScoreBusinessRules [id=" + id + ", groupName=" + groupName + ", categorization=" + categorization
            + ", subCategorization=" + subCategorization + ", riskAttribute=" + riskAttribute + ", parameters="
            + parameters + ", weighting=" + weighting + ", normalisedScore=" + normalisedScore + ", maximumScore="
            + maximumScore + ", actualScore=" + actualScore + ", lowValue=" + lowValue + ", mediumValue="
            + mediumValue + ", maxValue=" + maxValue + ", lastUpdatedBy=" + lastUpdatedBy + "]";
}

    public String getGroupName() {
    return groupName;
}

public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

public String getCategorization() {
    return categorization;
}

public void setCategorization(String categorization) {
    this.categorization = categorization;
}

public String getSubCategorization() {
    return subCategorization;
}

public void setSubCategorization(String subCategorization) {
    this.subCategorization = subCategorization;
}

public String getRiskAttribute() {
    return riskAttribute;
}

public void setRiskAttribute(String riskAttribute) {
    this.riskAttribute = riskAttribute;
}

public String getParameters() {
    return parameters;
}

public void setParameters(String parameters) {
    this.parameters = parameters;
}

public float getWeighting() {
    return weighting;
}

public void setWeighting(float weighting) {
    this.weighting = weighting;
}

public float getNormalisedScore() {
    return normalisedScore;
}

public void setNormalisedScore(int normalisedScore) {
    this.normalisedScore = normalisedScore;
}

public float getMaximumScore() {
    return maximumScore;
}

public void setMaximumScore(float maximumScore) {
    this.maximumScore = maximumScore;
}

public int getActualScore() {
    return actualScore;
}

public void setActualScore(int actualScore) {
    this.actualScore = actualScore;
}

public String getLowValue() {
    return lowValue;
}

public void setLowValue(String lowValue) {
    this.lowValue = lowValue;
}

public String getMediumValue() {
    return mediumValue;
}

public void setMediumValue(String mediumValue) {
    this.mediumValue = mediumValue;
}

public String getMaxValue() {
    return maxValue;
}

public void setMaxValue(String maxValue) {
    this.maxValue = maxValue;
}

public String getLastUpdatedBy() {
    return lastUpdatedBy;
}

public void setLastUpdatedBy(String lastUpdatedBy) {
    this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
}

public RiskScoreBusinessRules() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}

Pom.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.experian</groupId>
<artifactId>api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>experianAPI</name>
<description>Demo project for Experian</description>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-     8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: post some code..otherwise hard to tell where is the problem

Comment: please find the updated code added to the question